# VyOS / Vyatta multiple CIDR blocks on one side of IPSec tunnel

Tags: vpn, ipsec, vyatta

I am attempting to link an AWS VPC to a datacenter using the community VyOS AMI and IPSec tunneling, talking to a SonicWall device that I don't control.  I've been given the proper settings to establish a tunnel, but I need to pass traffic to two CIDR blocks through it, as below:

10.54.0.0/16 >> 10.64.0.0/10 and 10.64.0.0/9

I have traffic working through the tunnel to 10.64.0.0/10, but need to route to the other block as well.  Can I do this with one tunnel?

EDIT:  Here is the relevant config info, scrubbed for security:

```
esp-group espGroup1 {
     compression disable
     lifetime 28800
     mode tunnel
     pfs enable
     proposal 1 {
         encryption aes128
         hash sha1
     }
 }
 ike-group ikeGroup1 {
     key-exchange ikev1
     lifetime 28800
     proposal 1 {
         dh-group 2
         encryption aes128
         hash sha1
     }
 }
 site-to-site {
     peer <IP> {
         authentication {
             id <local IP>
             mode pre-shared-secret
             pre-shared-secret X
         }
         connection-type initiate
         default-esp-group espGroup1
         description "Tunnel"
         ike-group ikeGroup1
         local-address 10.54.0.5
         tunnel 1 {
             allow-nat-networks disable
             allow-public-networks disable
             local {
                 prefix 10.54.0.0/16
             }
             remote {
                 prefix 10.64.0.0/10
             }
         }
         tunnel 2 {
             allow-nat-networks disable
             allow-public-networks disable
             local {
                 prefix 10.54.0.0/16
             }
             remote {
                 prefix 10.128.0.0/9
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the config you've used to setup this tunnel please?

Comment: Added it to the question, as this comment box has a maximum character count for reasons passing understanding.

Comment: You can only specify a single prefix with this syntax so you would have to use an additional tunnel.  Is there any reason you couldn't use a VTI ?